# Query BYTEA in Postgres using sqlx

Tags: postgresql, rust, bytea, rust-sqlx

I have the following table in Postgres DB:

```
CREATE TABLE resources_index (
    hash varchar NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar NOT NULL,
    viewentry_id varchar NOT NULL,
    value bytea NULL
);
```

I'd like to execute the following prepared statement using `sqlx`:

```
SELECT
      t0.name,
      t0.value
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          name,
          value
        FROM
          resources_index
        WHERE
          hash = $1
          AND value :: BYTEA LIKE $2 :: BYTEA
      ) AS t0
    LIMIT
      $3
```

Problem occurs in the following line:
`AND value :: BYTEA LIKE $2 :: BYTEA`

Postgres DB error response is:
`ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea`

Query is executed as:

```
let mut q = sqlx::query_as::<sqlx::Postgres, IndexRow>(&query);
    for v in values.iter() {
        log::debug!("bind value {}", v);
        q = q.bind(v.as_bytes());
    }
    q.bind(limit).fetch_all(pool).await
```

For me it looks like `v` is casted to `VARCHAR` though it should be `BYTEA`.

Do you have any idea whether this is a bug or am I doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it using the inbuilt **decode** function.

```
SELECT
      t0.name,
      t0.value
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          name,
          value
        FROM
          resources_index
        WHERE
          hash = $1
          AND value LIKE decode($2, 'escape')
      ) AS t0
    LIMIT
      $3
```